# Create a running max column in DataFrame for each day

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
TimeStamp, Value
1-Jan 06:10, 5
1-Jan 08:15, 7
1-Jan 15:30, 3
2-Jan 07:05, 1
2-Jan 10:15, 3
2-Jan 13:30, 2
```

How can I add a third column to the same DataFrame that would show me the running max value of 'Value' for each day and reset with each next day? I want the DataFrame to look like this:

```
TimeStamp, Value, DayMax
1-Jan 06:10, 5, 7
1-Jan 08:15, 7, 7
1-Jan 15:30, 3, 7
2-Jan 07:05, 1, 3
2-Jan 10:15, 3, 3
2-Jan 13:30, 2, 3
```

I tried using `.rolling().max(...)` but problem is I need the max value even in earlier rows, before the max value is encountered, and also before `min_periods` are reached. Also I need the max to reset with each day, and thus to ignore the `window` parameter.

I am hoping to avoid looping and complex code manipulations, as I will be doing it over a very large DataFrame, so would much prefer something built-in!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you convert the TimeStamp column to a datetime using [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime) then you can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the date and call [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) to return a Series that is the max value for each day:

```
In [54]:
df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp'], format='%d-%b %H:%M')
df

Out[54]:
            TimeStamp  Value
0 1900-01-01 06:10:00      5
1 1900-01-01 08:15:00      7
2 1900-01-01 15:30:00      3
3 1900-01-02 07:05:00      1
4 1900-01-02 10:15:00      3
5 1900-01-02 13:30:00      2

In [55]:
df['DayMax'] = df.groupby(df['TimeStamp'].dt.date)['Value'].transform('max')
df

Out[55]:
            TimeStamp  Value  DayMax
0 1900-01-01 06:10:00      5       7
1 1900-01-01 08:15:00      7       7
2 1900-01-01 15:30:00      3       7
3 1900-01-02 07:05:00      1       3
4 1900-01-02 10:15:00      3       3
5 1900-01-02 13:30:00      2       3
```